Define category up front in ledger-cli
Here's some example transactions from the ledger manual:
2011/03/15   Trader Joe's
    Expenses:Groceries   $100.00
    Assets:Checking
2011/03/15   Whole Food Market
    Expenses:Groceries   $75.00
    Assets:Checking

Is there a way to define Checking as an Asset once up front so that I don't have to write Assets:Checking out each time?
So for example, something like this:
define Assets:Checking
define Expenses:Groceries

2011/03/15   Trader Joe's
    Groceries   $100.00
    Checking
2011/03/15   Whole Food Market
    Groceries   $75.00
    Checking


Gumnos provided an excellent answer here: link

If Gumnos is not on this stack, and doesn't care about this stack's internet points, you should feel free to copy that information over here as a self-answer. You can mark it as community wiki if you don't want to earn internet points from someone else's work :)

In Ledger CLI…
account Assets:Checking
    alias Checking
account Expenses:Groceries
    alias Groceries

2011/03/15   Trader Joe's
    Groceries   $100.00
    Checking
2011/03/15   Whole Food Market
    Groceries   $75.00
    Checking

Two things

define defines a variable
account defines an account (where money sits), "category" in your terms

In HLedger, this would be
account Expenses:Groceries
alias Groceries = Expenses:Groceries

The rest remain the same
